# Javascript: How to change TextGeometry on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I am working on the [ThreeJS geometry canvas text](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=text#canvas_geometry_text). The text is suppose to change to another text after a html button is clicked. However, it's not working. How can I change the TextGeometry on click event?

Here is what I'm working with:

```
 var theText = "Hello three.js! :)";

        var hash = document.location.hash.substr( 1 );

        if ( hash.length !== 0 ) {

            theText = hash;

        }

        var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( theText, {

            font: font,
            size: 80,
            height: 20,
            curveSegments: 2

        });

        geometry.computeBoundingBox();

        var centerOffset = -0.5 * ( geometry.boundingBox.max.x - geometry.boundingBox.min.x );

        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( [
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff, overdraw: 0.5 } ),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, overdraw: 0.5 } )
        ] );

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

        mesh.position.x = centerOffset;
        mesh.position.y = 100;
        mesh.position.z = 0;

        mesh.rotation.x = 0;
        mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI * 2;

        group = new THREE.Group();
        group.add( mesh );

        scene.add( group );
    }
      $('.button').on('click', function(e){
      theText.dispose();

       var menu= new Array('option1', 'option2', 'option3');
       theText=menu;

           });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to create another TextGeometry and mesh. Then on the click event you would remove the previous text with the new one.

```
function onMouseClick(){
    scene.remove(mesh_first);
    scene.add(mesh_second); 
}
```

For reference- https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js#L332